# Setting Content-Type in Django HttpResponse object for Shopify App

Tags: python, django, http, httpresponse, shopify

I'm working on a Shopify app using Django, which I am hosting on a VPS with nginx and gunicorn.

I am trying to change the Content-Type of an HttpResponse object to `application/liquid`, so that I can use Shopify's [application proxy feature](http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies), but it doesn't appear to be working.

Here is what I believe to be the relevant section of my code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
import shopify
from shopify_app.decorators import shop_login_required

def featured(request):
   response = HttpResponse()
   response['content_type'] = 'application/liquid; charset=utf-8'
   response['content'] = '<html>test123</html>'
   response['Content-Length'] = len(response.content)
   return response
```

According to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse), I should set `response[''content_type]` in order to set `Content-Type` in the header. Unfortunately, when I go to the URL corresponding to this function in views.py, I get a 200 response but the Content-Type has not changed and Content-Length is 0. Here are my response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 09 Jul 2013 12:26:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Request-Id: 2170c81fb16d18fc9dc056780c6d92fd
content: <html>test123</html>
vary: Cookie
content_type: application/liquid; charset=utf-8
P3P: CP="NOI DSP COR NID ADMa OPTa OUR NOR"
```

If I change `response['content_type']` to `response['Content-Type']`, I get the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 09 Jul 2013 12:34:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3097
Connection: keep-alive
X-Request-Id: 76e67e04b753294a3c37c5c160b42bcb
vary: Accept-Encoding
status: 200 OK
x-shopid: 2217942
x-request-id: 6e63ef3a27091c73a9e3fdaa03cc28cb
x-ua-compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
p3p: CP="NOI DSP COR NID ADMa OPTa OUR NOR"
content-encoding: gzip
P3P: CP="NOI DSP COR NID ADMa OPTa OUR NOR"
```

Any ideas on how I can change the Content-Type of the response? Might this be a problem with my nginx or gunicorn configurations?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 21):

Try the following:

```
def featured(request):
    content = '<html>test123</html>'

    response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='application/liquid')
    response['Content-Length'] = len(content)

    return response
```

A quick tip, you could add this into the `http` or `server` block part of your NGINX configuration so you don't have to specify the encoding within views and other Django code:

```
charset utf-8;
charset_types text/css application/json text/plain application/liquid;
```

Comment: Matt, thanks for the tip on the nginx configuration! I will definitely use that. Unfortunately, I have tried your code suggestion and it's returning a 411 Http error (length required). Attempting to specify the value of `length` or `Content-Length` as an argument in the HttpResponse results in Django errors (unexpected keyword argument and keyword can't be an expression).

Comment: `len(content)` should be `len(content.encode('utf-8)`

Answer (score 5):

So this worked for me:

```
def featured(request):
  response = HttpResponse("", content_type="application/liquid; charset=utf-8")
  response['Content-Length'] = len(content)
  response.write('<html>test123</html>')
  return response
```

Thanks, everyone, for the help!

Comment: You don't have to specify anything for content, i.e. response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')  , and then write to it as you did. Its also good to note you can get/set the content_type in the same way as length, response['Content-Type']

Answer (score 4):

Following the [instructions from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) it should be something like this:

```
# set content_type
response = HttpResponse("",
                        content_type="application/liquid; charset=utf-8")
# add content
response.write('<html>test123</html>')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Paulo, thanks for your help! As it turns out, when I tried this technique, I received a 411 Length Required error. However! Combining this with response['Content-Length'] = len(content) worked. Which is strange, since I didn't actually specify content... unless response.write automatically adds `<html>test123</html>` to the response's content? At any rate, thanks for the help!

Comment: It actually does. The docs says _But if you want to add content incrementally, you can use response as a file-like object_ . So  `.write` adds content to the response :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand the other answers, if the `HttpResponse` object already exists and its MIME type needs to be set after instantiating it (for example, when invoking a parent method), it can be achieved this way:

```
response = super(...)  # This returns some HttpResponse object
response["Content-Type"] = "application/liquid"
return response
```