# Get object list with ajax in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm using ajax in my django aplication, it works well except when I want to get all the registers in a table. I don't know how to send from my 'ajaxview' to the javascript code and then, how to parse the result.

Here is my **list.html**

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Birth date</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="clientList">
    <!--Here where I want to put the client list-->
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  getAllClients();
</script>
```

This is my **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from store_app import ajax as ajaxview
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^listClients/$', csrf_exempt(ajaxview.listClients), name='listClients'),
]
```

This is my **ajax.py** where I have diferent views than in views.py

```
def listClients(request):
    data = []
    clientlist = clients.objects.filter(clientstatus=1)
    #Here is where I don't know if I am doing correctly
    #I don't know how to send the client list or if I have to send it as a JSON
    #Please help here
    data.append({'clist':clientlist })
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

The last code actually work for other stuff, but not to send all the data

This is my **list.js** script

```
funtion getAllClients()
{
  $.ajax(
  {
    type: "POST",
    url: "/getAllClients/",
    data: "",
    success: function(result)
    {
      console.log(result); //Should I have a json object in 'result' variable?
      $.each(result, function(key, val)
      {
        //Here is where I want to parse each object and add to the HTML table
      });
    }
  });
}
```

This code give me an error in the browser console. Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: @Stack this is the error 'POST http://localhost:8000/listClients/ 500 (Internal Server Error)' so I think that the problem is in `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17548578/8150371  or use JsonResponse instead of HttpResponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea and depending on your django version, you could be correct. For django version <1.7, you have the correct syntax. For version 1.7 onwards, you should use a JsonResponse as such:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def listClients(request):
    data = []
    clientlist = clients.objects.filter(clientstatus=1)
    #Here is where I don't know if I am doing correctly
    #I don't know how to send the client list or if I have to send it as a JSON
    #Please help here
    data.append({'clist':clientlist })
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

In your AJAX request in the javascript, the result object will, in fact, be the json that you sent from the backend. And then in your .each() method you can add the list to the HTML.

While you can use the JsonResponse to solve this problem, I would also recommend looking into setting up django-rest-framework since you are creating, in essence, a rest API and could leverage the django-rest-framework library to make it much easier. This would require some overhead to learn but definitely could be useful if you need to make more APIs. Documentation is [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/).

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

You need to include a `csrftoken` in your request. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/

But also you should be using Class Based Views, and Django Forms to make these kinds of requests.

The other option that you have is to use the Django Templating language to insert the data that you want. Simply pass the data into the view's context_data.

Comment: OP is using csrf_exempt in his urls.py on the view, though I am not sure if it is implemented correctly

Comment: In my urls.py I have this csrf_exempt(ajaxview.listClients) so the problem is not csrf